# Forward declaration and friend functions

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have the following code

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()   {}
private:
    int foo_int;
    friend class bar;  //----->Statement A               
};

class bar 
{
public:
    void someMethod()
    {
        foo f;
        f.foo_int = 13;
    }
};
```

Now I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) answer on SO. However I cant put the pieces of puzzle together as to why 
the compiler recognizes bar as a type. I was under the impression that it would complain of Bar being an incomplete type however that did not happen. My question is why ?

Comment: You're not allocating a `bar` at that statement, so why do you expect the compiler to complain?

Comment: Yes that does make sense. Could you put that in as an answer

Comment: @JimBalter isn't this basically a duplicate of the linked question? I mean the answer is essentially there.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This question is specifically about `friend`, which isn't mentioned at the linked question. The question here is a bit baffling given the link, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> friend class bar;

is simply a declaration ... there's nothing for the compiler to complain about. The limitation on incomplete types is when the compiler needs information about the type that it doesn't have, such as its size or, for base classes, its members, but for `friend` it doesn't need anything other than its name.

Note that it doesn't matter where the `friend` declaration occurs in the class definition ... that it follows `private:` doesn't make it private. It's better to put it at the top of the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

A `friend` specification of a class that has not been declared yet acts as a declaration of the class. It is perfectly fine to declare an incomplete type as a friend of a class because the compiler only needs to know about the *type* being declared.